# How to setup Amazon Connect flow to collect caller's full name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I am developing an IVR system that needs to collect the user's full name.

I developed a Lex bot with a collectName intent that also has a firstName and lastName slot.

I have not added any utterances. I am trying to determine how exactly the integration with connect works. I have tried plugging it into my flow on the canvas with the intent collectName, but it reads the TTS prompt I added and disconnects.

Any advice?

I created an Amazon Lex Bot. The intent within the lex bot is called collectName. With this intent, I added two slots. one of which is firstName and the other which is lastName. They have the associated prompts: "Please speak your first name," and "please speak your last name" respectively.

When I integrate the lex bot into my Amazon connect flow with the intent listed as collectName, it reads the TTS in the get customer input block and disconnects.

What I would like is for it to run through the intent and collect he information for those slots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things...

First, in your lex bot intent set an utterance to `{firstName} {lastName}` This way, if you have the prompt, "Please tell me your name." It will pick that up without having to ask again. Also, if the caller only says their first name, they'll get prompted for their last name.

Once this is done when the call comes back from the lex bot you can use the `$.Lex.Slots.firstName` and `$.Lex.Slots.lastName` attributes as needed in your flow.

If this isn't working, you'll need to look at your contact flow logs in cloudwatch to see what is going wrong.